# Correct way to use EJB Asynchronous methods

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, websphere

I have two tasks that I need to perform say `task1` and `task2` which are a part of same business process. I have to give response to the end user when `task1` completes so it's response time have to be minimized.

My current approach is to perform `task1` and as soon as `task1` is finished, invoke `task2` method asynchronously. `task2` is complicated and it's response time is out of my control as it has some external dependency.

```
@Stateless
public class SessionBean1 {

    @Inject
    SessionBean2 sessionBean2;

    public void doTask1(){
        // task one stuff
        sessionBean2.doTask2();
    }

}



@Stateless
public class SessionBean2 {

    @Asynchronous
    public void doTask2(){
        // do task2 stuff
    }

}
```

In websphere 8.0 (the EJB container in use) synchronous methods and asynchronous methods are run by different thread pools.

My initial assumption was that even if `task2` is performing badly, `task1` would have no impact, but sadly that's not true.

If `task2` is performing badly, all threads from asynchronous thread pool will be occupied. This will cause `task1` to wait for asynchronous threads to be free and hence `task1` has impact.

The message in websphrere server logs : 
`The request buffer for thread pool WorkManager.WebSphere_EJB_Container_AsynchMethods_Internal_WorkManager has reached its capacity`

My question is what would be a proper way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: If you were using Java EE 7, you could use the @AccessTimeout(value = xx) annotation , but I think Websphere is Java EE 6 ?

Comment: @mattfreake: As in the linked [image](http://2.1m.yt/itzn6So.jpg),  the no of async method requests are limited and are dependent on number of async threads. I can increase the no of threads but even if for a few minutes task2 performs badly, my task1 will still have to wait. Also the no of threads are limited by hardware configuration.

Comment: The idea of using a JMS queue suggested by @rjdkolb is a much better idea if sizing the thread pool is problematical.

Comment: @SteveC: Currently I'm adding the method parameters for `task2` to a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and then polling them and calling the method `task2` periodically with the help of a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Timer.html). So far it has turned out to be good. Using JMS might be an overkill as both `task1` and `task2` are on the same server.

Comment: All Java EE implementations have JMS "built in" and therefore can run in the "same server".

Comment: @SteveC: Yes but there'll be the overhead of Serialization and  message headers.

Comment: @ares, I use JMS queues on my local app server all the time.
A user 'click' in my environment can only take 2 seconds to respond, so I fire off JMS messages for anything in the click that can be run in the background. 
I send a simple comma separated string to JMS and unmashal in the MDB.
The disadvantages are a bit of boiler plate code for the MDB and JMS queue poisoning is possible. So test for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative would be to increase the "Work request queue size" of the "EJB asynchronous method invocation settings" in the Admin Console. This is a queue, before the actual thread pool itself, so this might buy you some more time.

Ideally this should be used in combination with the timeouts suggested above.

Comment: That seems a good option. By default it's handled by run time and dependent on no of threads allocated but I can't figure out how many. Does the last line from websphrere admin console `The runtime currently uses the larger of 20 and the value of maximum number of threads.` makes any sense?

Comment: Looking at your image, I take it as "the larger of 15 or 20", so in your case it should be 20. You can keep the 15 maximum thread-pool size, and increase your queue to something much larger. I'd *hope* the queue should have a small memory/processor footprint, so it can store your waiting requests for task2, while letting the existing ones finish and keeping within your hardware limits. But if the task2s can take an indefinite time to finish, then I think timeouts would be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I think [@AccessTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AccessTimeout.html) is what you are looking for. I see an example [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/async-methods/README.html) 
This will limit the amount of time that .doTask2() can run and avoid your problem.

```
@Stateless
public class SessionBean1 {

    @Inject
    SessionBean2 sessionBean2;

    public void doTask1(){
        // task one stuff
        sessionBean2.doTask2();
    }

}
```

***SessionBean2***

```
@Stateless
public class SessionBean2 {
    @AccessTimeout(60000)//default timeunit is TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    @Asynchronous
    public void doTask2(){
        // do task2 stuff
    }

}
```

**As an alternative :**

To limit the time the async process can take, use the handle.get(xx, TimeUnit.xx); method. You will also need to return Future and not just void to make it work.

I hope this suits your use case as you will need to call a .get

```
@Stateless
public class SessionBean1 {

    @Inject
    SessionBean2 sessionBean2;

    public void doTask1(){
        // task one stuff
        Future<Void> handle = sessionBean2.doTask2();
        // do other stuff
        handle.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//If you want to block later

    }

}
```

***SessionBean2***

```
@Stateless
public class SessionBean2 {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<Void> doTask2(){
        // do task2 stuff
        new AsyncResult<Void>(Void);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll load test after adding the @AccessTimeout and let you know the results. But in cases when the call will actually timeout, my task2 would not be called.

Comment: If you want it to be asynchronous and always run, rather put a message a JMS queue

Comment: ...or use an EJB timer, which is likely easier to use.